# Can't delete data from DataGridview using C# (store procedure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, datagridview

I made a small c# windows program.Which add some data from windows form and show it in gridview. I can save data without any problem.And,I made a delete button to delete data by clicking on gridview cell click. but unfortunately i can't delete data.Though I find the problem but can't find the solution.The problem is, 'Id' can't be pass by double clicking.Here is my program design image-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktLut.png)

Here is my design code part.

```
  private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rows = aRegistrationBLL.Delete(aRegistrationProperty);

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registartion Delete sucessfully.");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registartion Delete failed.");

        }

    }
```

Here is my BLL code part

```
   internal int Delete(RegistrationProperty aRegistrationProperty)
  {
      try
      {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteUser", aRegistationDLL.GetConn());

          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];

          param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
          param[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(aRegistrationProperty.Id);
          cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

          return aRegistationDLL.ExeNonQuery(cmd);

      }

      catch
      {
          throw;
      }


  }
```

Here is my DLL code part -

```
  public int ExeNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.Connection = GetConn();
        int rowsAffected = -1;
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        aDBconnection.conn.Close();
        return rowsAffected;

    }
```

Here,is my RegistrationProperty.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegistrationAPP.Model
```

{

```
public class RegistrationProperty

{
    private string name;
    private string gender;
    private string dateOfBirth;
    private string address;
    private string education;
    private string userName;
    private string password;
    private string confirmPassword;
    public int Id;


    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }

    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get
        {
            return gender;
        }
        set
        {
            gender = value;
        }

    }

    public string DateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return dateOfBirth;
        }

        set
        {
            dateOfBirth = value;
        }

    }


    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }

        set
        {
            address = value;
        }
    }

    public string Education
    {
        get
        {
            return education;
        }

        set
        {
            education = value;
        }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return userName;
        }

        set
        {
            userName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return password;
        }

        set
        {
            password = value;
        }
    }

    public string ConfirmPassword
    {
        get
        {
            return confirmPassword;
        }
        set
        {
            confirmPassword = value;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here, is my store procedure for delete data-

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[DeleteUser]
@Id int
as
delete from RegistrationTable where Id=@Id
```

Comment: Where do you get the `aRegistrationProperty` in the `deleteButton_Click` event handler?

Comment: RegistrationProperty.cs is my propery class . I just call them with initialize in the top(which i can't put here because it would be very large code)

Comment: public RegistrationDAL aRegistationDLL = new RegistrationDAL();